# Is it possible to derive a new style from an existing style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is there a convention in TikZ for defining a new style as an extension of an existing style?

As it stands, I can do:

```
a/.style    = { black, very thin }
```

Then I could extend this style locally within, e.g., a scope:

```
\begin{scope}[a/.append style = { thick }]
  …
\end{scope}
```

or I could define an entire new style:

```
b/.style    = { black, thick }
```

but this requires replicating the shared style information across both `a` and `b`.

It seems there could be some way of specifying `b` as an extension of `a` (everywhere equivalent to "appending" `b`'s definitions to `a`'s definitions), akin to:

```
b/.style    = { extends = a, thick }
```

or:

```
b/.inherits = a,
b/.style    = { thick }
```

Is there a canonical answer in TikZ beyond just "use a TeX macro to define the shared contents"?

Comment: You could just do `b/.style={a, thick}`, or `b/.style={a}` and then somewhere `b/.append style={thick}`. `.style` *is* `.inherits` but you will need to use `.append style` then (or `.prefix style` if settings from `a` should overwrite those given in `.prefix style`).

Comment: I agree.  There is nothing magic about styles; they are just keys that expand to other keys.  To extend them, you include them in your own list of keys.

Comment: You're both right. I'm glad to accept this as an answer if you make it one. Thanks. (The consequences of a purely macro-based language still take some getting used to!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering my own question for the sake of others: the comments on my question are correct.

In particular, as to the two pseudo-syntaxes for extending or inheriting from an existing style which I sketched, `.style` *is* `.inherits`, and just using the key `a` is equivalent to `extends = a` since `a` expands to all the keys defined in `a/.style`.

So the easy answers are simply:

```
a/.style = { black, very thin },
b/.style = { a, thick } % copy styles of "a", then append "thick" which overrides "very thin"
```

or:

```
b/.prefix style = a, % equivalent to putting "a" at the start of b's style definition above
% later...
b/.style = { thick }
```

The reference I was struggling to find when searching for this myself was the `pgfkeys` package documented in Sec. 63 of the current TikZ/PGF reference manual.

All credit due to @Qrrbrbirlbel and @Ryan Reich.