# Initialize a pgfkey with style and defaults (as in object constructors)

Tags: pgfkeys

Using `pgfkeys`, I'd like to initialize keys as in setting attributes with an object constructor.

Such that I can create keys `/Photo/May`, `/Photo/June` etc. based on some initial properties of `/Photo`, and set some default values.

[Apparently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137192/is-it-possible-to-derive-a-new-style-from-an-existing-style) this should be easy, but I don't seem to interpret the manual correctly:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/Photo/May/defaults' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /Photo/.is family, /Photo,
  init/.style = {
    defaults/.style = {file = {}, bleed = 0pt},
    file/.initial = {},
    bleed/.initial = {},
  }
}

% #1 = options, #2 = photo name
\newcommand\SetPhoto[2][]{%
  \pgfkeys{%
    /Photo/#2/.is family, /Photo/#2,
    /Photo/#2/.append style=/Photo/init,
    defaults, file={#2},
    #1%
  }%
}

\newcommand\DoPhoto[1]{%
  % suppose it was an image...
  \hskip -\pgfkeysvalueof{/Photo/#1/bleed}%
  \frame{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Photo/#1/file}}%
}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% somewhere early in the document
\SetPhoto{May}%
\SetPhoto[bleed=3mm]{June}%
\SetPhoto[bleed=5mm]{July}%

% typeset the photos with the given options 

\DoPhoto{May}

\DoPhoto{June}

\DoPhoto{July}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha! You don't `.append style=/Photo/init`, you just just call `/Photo/init` to apply the style set in it.

```
% #1 = options, #2 = photo name
\newcommand\SetPhoto[2][]{%
  \pgfkeys{%
    /Photo/#2/.is family, /Photo/#2,
    /Photo/init,
    defaults, file={#2},
    #1%
  }%
}
```

So the correct mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /Photo/.is family, /Photo,
  init/.style = {
    defaults/.style = {file = {}, bleed = 0pt},
    file/.initial = {},
    bleed/.initial = {},
  }
}

% #1 = options, #2 = photo name
\newcommand\SetPhoto[2][]{%
  \pgfkeys{%
    /Photo/#2/.is family, /Photo/#2,
    /Photo/init,
    defaults, file={#2},
    #1%
  }%
}

\newcommand\DoPhoto[1]{%
  % suppose it was an image...
  \hskip -\pgfkeysvalueof{/Photo/#1/bleed}%
  \frame{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Photo/#1/file}}%
}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% somewhere early in the document
\SetPhoto{May}%
\SetPhoto[bleed=3mm]{June}%
\SetPhoto[bleed=5mm]{July}%

% typeset the photos with the given options 

\DoPhoto{May}

\DoPhoto{June}

\DoPhoto{July}

\end{document}
```